# How to remove XML attributes in PostgreSQL?

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have this SQL query right now:

```
SELECT * FROM "ir_ui_view" WHERE
    XMLEXISTS('//tree[@editable]' PASSING BY REF XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT "arch_db")) OR
    XMLEXISTS('//tree[@multi_edit]' PASSING BY REF XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT "arch_db"))
;
```

Based from that query... how can I remove `editable` and `multi_edit` attributes from `<tree>` ?

Let say I have:

```
<tree editable="top"></tree>
```

I want it to be:

```
<tree></tree>
```

Thank you!